# A qué se debe este error 404 cargando archivo PHP en Xampp?

Tags: php, html

Estoy empezando en php y cuando abro el localhost y escribo todo para imprimir me da error 404

Ya borre xampp y lo volvi a instalar, busque video y lo he hecho de todas las maneras y no me sale, alguien por favor que me explique.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestranos tus árbol de carpetas y archivos, por que un error 404 es por que la ruta que escribes no existe tal cual

Comment: Pues es que no tenemos idea de dónde pusiste ese archivo hola.php en el servidor. Nos puedes mostrar? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

de acuerdo a tu configuración, busca la carpeta root de tu servicio web. Es en esa carpeta, y solo esa carpeta, donde debes dejar tu "index.php". En tu caso, la carpeta root es llamada al escribir "localhost" y además, en tu caso, tienes una subcarpeta "curso" que debe estar dentro de root.